# Automate redirection after form validation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following piece of code:

```
        if(Request::ajax())
        {                    
            $response_values = array(
                'validation_failed' => 1,
                'errors' => $validator->errors->toArray()
            );
            return Response::json($response_values);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::route("resource.create")
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator->errors);
        }
```

I have this a lot in my code, and would like to find a way to automate this.

I tried creating a method in BaseController but it doesn't redirect properly, I also tried an after filter, but I was unable to pass parameters to this after filter, as I would need to pass errors and route.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: "...but it doesn't redirect properly", what happens?

Comment: Agree with @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, you may need to give more info on the method you tried creating. Otherwise Antonio's answer below should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working for you?

```
class BaseController extends \Controller {

    public function processAndRedirectError($validator)
    {
        if(Request::ajax())
        {                    
            $response_values = array(
                'validation_failed' => 1,
                'errors' => $validator->errors->toArray()
            );
            return Response::json($response_values);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::route("resource.create")
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator->errors);
        }
    }

}

class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(...);

        return $this->processAndRedirectError($validator);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing, I wasn't returning the method from the BaseController, just calling it. Thank you for the quick reply Mr. Ribeiro.